# NiFi splitting JSON arrays

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi

I'm trying to use NiFi to transform a JSON file into CSV but I'm struggeling with an array. My JSON file looks like this:

```html
{
    "id": "24",
    "name": "",
    "height": [
        500.0,
        99999.0
    ],
    "average": [
        -2.0,
        -5.0
    ]
}
```

To get the correct CSV output, I need to split the array so my output will look like this (as a JSON still):

```html
[
{
  "id" : "24",
  "name" : "",
  "height" : 500,
  "average" : -2
},
 {
  "id" : "24",
  "name" : "",
  "height" : 99999,
  "average" : -5
 }
]
```

I've tried several different ways, like a JOLT specification and splitting my JSON at $.height.* but nothing seems to work. I thought splitting the flowFile might be the way to go but if I split at $.height.* I only get the values and loose the rest of the flowfile content (which I still need to split the next array). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOLT can probably do it, but it's got some deficits on the documentation, so this Groovy code should work in a pinch for you in `ExecuteScript`:

```
import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.*

def flowFile = session.get()

if (flowFile) {
    def out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
    session.exportTo(ff, out)
    out.close()

    def rawText = new String(out.toByteArray())
    def parsed = slurper.parseText(rawText)

    def results = []

    //This does assume that the length of the two arrays is always the same
    parsed.each { record ->
        1.upto(record["height"].size() -1) { index ->
            def newResult = [
                id: record["id"],
                name: record["name"],
                height: record["height"][index],
                average: record["average"][index]
            ]

            results << newResult
        }
    }

    flowFile = session.write({
        it.write(prettyPrint(toJson(results)).bytes)
    } as OutputStreamCallback)

    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
}
```

Feel free to join the nifi-users mailing list to ask for help on how to approach this with JOLT.

Comment: Thanks a million!! I've been stuck on this for quite a while now!

Comment: It doesn't work quite yet. I changed "ff" in session.exportTo(ff, out) to "flowFile" (I'm guessing that's what you meant) but now I always get the error "No such property: height for class". I'm pretty sure that I get this error if "height" is not an array but only one single attribute. I'm currently trying to build an if statement to only execute the parsing part if "height" is actually an array but I've never written Groovy code before so I haven't found a working solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution to my problem, using the ExecuteScript Processor with the following Groovy Skript:

```groovy
import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.*
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def flowFile = session.get()

if (flowFile) {
    def out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
    session.exportTo(flowFile, out)
    out.close()

    def rawText = new String(out.toByteArray())
    def parsed = slurper.parseText(rawText)
    
    if(parsed.mgrenze instanceof java.util.List) {

        def results = []

        parsed.height.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
            def newResult = [
              id : parsed.id,
              name : parsed.name,
              height : item,
              average : parsed.average[index]
                ]

                results << newResult
        }

        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {outputStream ->
            outputStream.write(prettyPrint(toJson(results)).bytes)
        } as OutputStreamCallback)
    }

    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
}
```